# why form.is_valid() is always false?

Tags: python, django

I tried to create a `contact us` form in django but i got always false when i want to use `.is_valid()` function.

**this is my form:**

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'نام خود را وارد کنید'}),
        label="نام ",
        validators=[
            validators.MaxLengthValidator(100, "نام شما نمیتواند بیش از 100 کاراکتر باشد")])

    last_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'نام خانوادگی خود را وارد کنید'}),
        label="نام خانوادگی",
        validators=[
            validators.MaxLengthValidator(100, "نام خانوادگی شما نمیتواند بیش از 100 کاراکتر باشد")])

    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'ایمیل خود را وارد کنید'}),
        label="ایمیل",
        validators=[
            validators.MaxLengthValidator(200, "تعداد کاراکترهایایمیل شما نمیتواند بیش از ۲۰۰ کاراکتر باشد.")
        ])

    title = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'عنوان پیام خود را وارد کنید'}),
        label="عنوان",
        validators=[
            validators.MaxLengthValidator(250, "تعداد کاراکترهای  شما نمیتواند بیش از 250 کاراکتر باشد.")
        ])

    text = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'متن پیام خود را وارد کنید'}),
        label="متن پیام",
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__()
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form_field require'
```

**this is my view:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import ContactForm
from .models import ContactUs


def contact_us(request):
    contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if contact_form.is_valid():
        first_name = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        last_name = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        email = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        title = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('title')
        text = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('text')

        ContactUs.objects.create(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, title=title, text=text)
        # todo: show user success message

        contact_form = ContactForm()
    context = {
        'form': contact_form
    }

    return render(request, 'contact_us/contact_us.html', context)
```

** this is the codes in template**

```
  <form action="{% url 'contact' %}" id="contactform" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form_block">
                                        {{ form.first_name }}
                                        {% for error in form.first_name.errors %}
                                            <p class="text-danger">{{ error }}</p>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form_block">
                                        {{ form.last_name }}
                                        {% for error in form.last_name.errors %}
                                            <p class="text-danger">{{ error }}</p>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form_block">
                                        {{ form.email }}
                                        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                                            <p class="text-danger">{{ error }}</p>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form_block">
                                        {{ form.title }}
                                        {% for error in form.title.errors %}
                                            <p class="text-danger">{{ error }}</p>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form_block">
                                        {{ form.text }}
                                        {% for error in form.text.errors %}
                                            <p class="text-danger">{{ error }}</p>
                                        {% endfor %}

                                        <div class="response"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form_block">
                                        <button type="submit" class="clv_btn submitForm"
                                                data-type="contact">ارسال
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: in your code I see you are not checking the http method if its a post or get.also you still render the form even when the form is valid.Is data not saved in database or how have you figured that the form is always invalid??

Comment: data is not saving in databace

Comment: do you mind using class based views?

Comment: i dont care about class based or function base i just want to save data

Comment: When form.is_valid() is False, then form.errors contains one or more errors. Try adding "print(form.errors)" to the view - this should give you an idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: i printed that but its contains nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the super() constructor in **init** override at forms.py:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form_field require'
```

Fix your view based on [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#the-view):

```
def contact_us(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if contact_form.is_valid():
            ContactUs.objects.create(**contact_form.cleaned_data)
            messages.success(request, 'My success message')
            # you want to send to your home
            return redirect('/contact')

    else:
        contact_form = ContactForm()
    context = {
        'form': contact_form
    }

    return render(request, 'contact_us.html', context)
```

I took the liberty to clean up your view by using **kwargs since you have many fields. Used [Django messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages) to display successful message on obj creation. Here is how to [display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages) it.

Comment: thanks it works. it was because of __init__ code but i don't know why

Comment: Because you were calling super() constructor in the wrong way, I've updated the answer.